# How do I get google to show my page's structure in its results?

Tags: google, google-search, sitemap, search-results, site-structure

I know that for some pages Google lists the results as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, main navigation pages (About, Constructed, Contact etc.) are shown in an indented and table-like manner before the other results (`urbalize.tumblr.com` etc.) are shown.

My question is: How can I get Google to show the results of my (wordpress) page in the same way?

What I already tried: I assumed that submitting my sitemap (via `sitemap.xml`) to Google would help, but it didnt.

Is there anything else I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

They are called Sitelinks and you can't force Google, but it helps if:

- Google thinks your site is a brand / very important for a keyword
- Your site has a clear hierarchy and strategie for internal links
- Breadcrumb implementation with schema.org to help Google to understand the hierarchy
- Use text as link and not images..
- Offer a sitemap (as you did)
- I assume your project is new, i think it will need some time too
- .. do good SEO in general ;)

You can only demote existing Sitelinks in the Searchconsole (Webmastertools).

If you use AdWords you can activate them in your Ads.